# Remove rows from one dataframe that is present in another dataframe depending on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as shown below:

```
df1 =
      A     B    val1     val2   val3
     
0     0    45     20      200      100       
1     3    100    10      80       50      
2     4    30     30      60       10  
3     6    150    50      34       11
```

```
df2 =
      A     B    val1     val2   val3
     
0     4    30     80      145      90      
1     0    45     10      80       50      
2     1    78     10      90       18
```

I want to remove the rows from `df1` that are present in `df2` only depending on the columns `A` and `B`. From `df1`, the values 0 & 45 and 4 & 30 are present in `df2` in columns `A` and `B`. So I want the entire row from `df1` to be removed. The final dataframe should be as follows:

```
final = 
      A     B    val1     val2   val3
     
       
0     3    100    10      80       50        
1     6    150    50      34       11
```

The index should be reset to 0 and 1 in the final dataframe
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `df2.loc[~df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])]`, if you want to consider more columns use `df2.merge(df1, on=col_list, how='left', indicator=True)` and filter based on the indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter columns names for `df2` and add `indicator` parameter to [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, test column `_merge` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df1[df1.merge(df2[['A','B']], indicator=True, how='left')['_merge'].eq('left_only')]
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   A    B  val1  val2  val3
1  3  100    10    80    50
3  6  150    50    34    11
```

Or create `MultiIndex` and use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with invert mask:

```
df = (df1[~df1.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['A','B']).index)]
           .reset_index(drop=True)))
print (df)
   A    B  val1  val2  val3
1  3  100    10    80    50
3  6  150    50    34    11
```